# know how many watts a USB device is consuming

Tags: usb, power

I know it's possible to do some electric hack to know how much current a device is using... but that would be a 1 time usage so it would be a waste of money and parts.

Is it possible to know that using software in Mac OS?

There's no BIOS in Mac OS, but I presume through EFI the OS should be able to access that kind of low level info.

Answer (score 0):

System Information shows how much current devices tell they require at most:

[image]

The voltage for USB (including 2.0 and 3.0) is about 5 V, so 98 mA is about 0.49 W. For some devices the required current is just shown as 500 mA (the USB 2.0 maximum), and I don't know how to see how much energy devices actually consume.

Comment: I already saw that info in System Information, but it doesn't say how much power the device is actually using... only the max allowed.